# Code change works in local machine but not in staging server

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-connection

In a predetermined format, csv files can be uploaded and in the process it gets pursed through an algorithm every time we upload a dataset. One of the categories for check is the name of the countries in the world and country groups (continents and/or regions) to categorize the data. Recently, we are trying to add international organization names to this list as the data can be categorized based on this. To implement the list of countries and country groups, Ruby script that reads data from a CSV file (data/wesis_unique_cow_entities_v2020-06-23.csv), processes it, and imports it into a database table.

'create_country' method creates/updates a Country record in the database based on the data provided in the current hash. All the country group relations are provided through a json file. After adding the international organization names and codes in the country and country groups, I ran the code in localhost. It performed the DB migration on its own and the code is working perfectly. I wanted to test it in the staging server. The deployment runs without any errors and the branch is active in the server. But the changes regarding international organizations are not visible. I checked the staging server DB (postgreSQL) and the entries are not there. We have erased the cache and redeployed the branch, sill the same. Can anyone give me an idea what can we do to resolve this?

I have checked the table contents in the database and the new country name and groups entities are not available in the database. I have erased the DB cache in case the previous entries are stored there. Instead of a new file name with updated data, I kept the old filename but changed the file content. Tried erasing one of the existing country group relations to see if the changes are really being implemented, it could not find the erased entry so it is working as expected.

My expectation from the changes is that the new entries would get updated the staging DB and subsequently, in the production server. Also, the user is able to choose the international organizations in the drop down in the data explorer page to look for relevant data.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

file = SmarterCSV.process("data/wesis_unique_cow_entities_v2020-06-23.csv",{ remove_empty_values: true, col_sep: ';'})

def create_country current
    country = Country.where( "entity_id = ? ", current[:cow_code].to_i).take
    if country.nil?
        country = Country.new
    end

    country.entity_id = current[:cow_code].to_i
    country.entity_name = current[:country_name]

    unless current[:independent_list].nil?
        independence_list = relation_year_string_to_array current[:independent_list]
        independence_hash = Hash.new
        independence_list.each do |tuple|
            independence_hash[tuple[0].to_i] = tuple[1].to_i
        end
        country.independence_hash = independence_hash
    end

    if current[:pop_over_500k].kind_of? Integer
        country.pop_over_500k = current[:pop_over_500k] == 1
    elsif current[:pop_over_500k].kind_of? String
        country.pop_over_500k = current[:pop_over_500k].delete(" ").eql?("1")
    end
    country.wiki_url = current[:wiki_url]

    unless current[:alternative_names].nil?
        alternative_names = current[:alternative_names].split(",").map!{|s| s.strip}
        country.alternative_names = alternative_names
    end

    unless current[:remark].nil?
        remark = current[:remark].split(";").map!{|s| s.strip}
        country.remark = remark
    end

    unless current[:vdem_historical_names].nil?
        vdem_historical_names = current[:vdem_historical_names].split(";").map!{|s| s.strip}
        country.vdem_historical_names = vdem_historical_names
    end

    unless current[:cow_abb].nil?
        cow_abb = current[:cow_abb].strip
        country.cow_abb = cow_abb
    end

    unless current[:iso3c].nil?
        iso3c_abb = current[:iso3c].strip
        country.iso3c_abb = iso3c_abb
    end

    unless current[:iso3n].nil?
        iso3n_abb = current[:iso3n]
        country.iso3n_abb = iso3n_abb.to_i
    end

    country.save!

    if(!current[:related_list].nil? && !current[:relation_year].nil? && !current[:relation_type].nil?)
        create_relations current, country
    end
end

def string_to_array string_array
    #trim the brackets and delete white space
    trimmed_string = string_array[1..-2].delete(" ")
    return trimmed_string.split(",")
end

def relation_year_string_to_array string_array
    #trim the brackets and delete white space
    trimmed_string = string_array[1..-2].delete(" ")

    full_array = []
    tuple_item1 = ""
    tuple_item2 = ""
    started_first = false
    started_second = false
    trimmed_string.split('').each do |character|
        if character.eql?("(")
            started_first = true
            next
        elsif character.eql?(",")
            if(started_first == true)
                started_second = true
            end
            started_first = false;
            next
        elsif character.eql?(")")
            started_second = false
            full_array.push([tuple_item1, tuple_item2])
            tuple_item1 = ""
            tuple_item2 = ""
        end
        if started_first == true
            tuple_item1 += character
        elsif started_second == true
            tuple_item2 += character
        end

    end
    return full_array
end

def create_relations current, country
    related_list = string_to_array current[:related_list]
    relation_year_list = relation_year_string_to_array current[:relation_year]
    relation_type_list = string_to_array current[:relation_type]

    if(related_list.count > relation_type_list.count || related_list.count > relation_year_list.count)
        #if there are more relation ids than relation types or relation years
        return
    end


    related_list.each_with_index do |related_id, index|
        relation_start = relation_year_list[index][0].to_i
        relation_end = relation_year_list[index][1].to_i
        relation_type = relation_type_list[index].to_i


        unless country.nil?
            faulty_rel = Relation.where("country_id =? AND (relation_start =? OR relation_end =? OR relation_type =? )", country, 0, 0, 0).take
            if(!faulty_rel.nil?)
                faulty_rel.destroy!
            end

            check = Relation.where("country_id = ? AND related_country_cow_code = ? AND relation_start = ? AND relation_type = ?",
            country, related_id.to_i, relation_start, relation_type).take

            if !check.nil?
                if check.update!(country_id: country.id,
                    related_country_cow_code: related_id.to_i,
                    relation_start: relation_start,
                    relation_end: relation_end,
                    relation_type: relation_type)
                end
                next
            end

            relation = Relation.new
            relation.country = country
            relation.related_country_cow_code = related_id.to_i
            relation.relation_start = relation_start
            relation.relation_end = relation_end
            relation.relation_type = relation_type
            relation.save!


        end

    end


end


file.each_with_index do |current, index|

    create_country current

end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cmx8.jpg)
```

Comment: The migrations did not run.  Check your deployment logs.

Comment: Look at the Postgres log and see what is actually hitting the database. It may also show errors that are not making it through to your code.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. We use deploy user for all of the deployment work. I am getting the following error in the postgres log.

2024-03-17 06:25:13.838 CET [13792] root@root FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
2024-03-17 06:25:13.838 CET [13792] root@root DETAIL:  User "root" has no password assigned.
 Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"